# The Path of Evolution Post a Mass Extinction

Tags: evolution, climate, science-in-society, extinction

So an asteroid cluster wipes out 95% of life on earth. It kills all carnivores, most herbivores, and almost all of photosynthetic life (Humans survive but I am concerned on non-intelligent life). The internet tells me that scientists believe it takes billions of years for earth to regain its full biodiversity. Focusing on the evolution of land dwelling creatures over the first thousand years, what kind of life would flourish? Weeds and insects?

This is my first question on the forum. Let me know how I can improve future questions.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE, Novus! This is an interesting question, but seems a bit too broad. A whole book can be written just to answer this. I think we might already have some interesting question on extinction. Try searching around for "earth exctinction" and see if something can help answer your question. Meanwhile, have fun with the Worldbuilding!

Comment: The other mass extinctions only took a few million years for biodiversity to return. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_event#Effects_and_recovery A few thousand years is very short for evolution.

Comment: The subject you are interested in is called [*speculative evolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_evolution). The Wikipedia article mentions numerous books; I recommend Peter Ward's and Alexis Rockman's *[Future Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Evolution)*.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the race will go to the small, fast breeding species. They can rapidly fill open ecological niches, and their high rate of reproduction means positive mutations which allow them to thrive in different niches will also rapidly spread.

British author [Dougal Dixon](https://infogalactic.com/info/Dougal_Dixon) wrote a book many years ago called "[After Man: A Zoology of the Future](https://infogalactic.com/info/After_Man)" which speculated on this very topic. Rats are not only prolific breeders, but also capable of living in a wide variety of ecological niches. This allows them to move into a wider range of environments, where some will remain and begin specializing in exporting that environment (since specialists will tend to outperform generalists, the evolving rats will do better than baseline rats). The book speculated that rats would eventually speciate into analogues of most land creatures, ranging from a deer analogue to a "sabre toothed tiger" analogue.

[image]

*Rats evolved into deer and sabre tooth tiger analogues*

Other small creatures will also rush into open niches, so there will be fierce competition in many cases. Other niches may remain open for a long time, as they are very specialized, but eventually something might move into the spot. In Dixon's book, penguins evolve to replace the now extinct dolphins and whales, which seems logical given their high level of adaptation to the sea and prolific numbers (but don't count out the seals and otters)

[image]

*Penguins become dolphin and whale analogues*

So the general rule will be look for small, fast breeding species which can fill ecological niches. The ones which are more adaptable will generally have the ability to fill more and more diverse niches, unless a better adapted specialist is already filling the spot.

Comment: Amazing answer! Where did you get the illustrations?

Comment: These are some of the illustrations from "After Man". Type the title into your search engine and then go to illustrations

Answer (score 4):

> The internet tells me that scientists believe it takes billions of years for earth to regain its full biodiversity

I think you need a better internet. It's only been 250 million years since [the big one](https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/dinosaurs-ancient-fossils-new-discoveries/extinction/mass-extinction/), and there's been two smaller mass extinctions in between (not counting the one we're currently perpetrating).

In thousands of years you'll get little morphological evolution (everything will still look mostly like its present-day ancestors) but a lot of behavioral evolution as the surviving species with the most adaptability take over ecological niches that have become vacant.

Answer (score 2):

If an asteroid cluster "kills all carnivores, most herbivores, and almost all of photosynthetic life", then there's not much left. The plants are almost entirely gone. The few remaining herbivores will soon run out of food -- unless any surviving seeds can germinate. The absence of carnivores will allow herbivores to flourish and that's a problem. Whatever plants will, once more, be soon be eaten.

Since the question asks whether insects and weeds, this suggests the OP may not consider the insects are also carnivores and herbivores. This could be a case of implicit mammal chauvinism. Somewhat to be expected, since there's a lot of about. It's tempting to tidy up this post-catastrophe world and get rid of the insects too.

It's possible humble organisms like [nematodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nematode) will survive. They are ubiquitous and extremely diverse; the parasitic varieties probably won't.

> Nematodes have successfully adapted to nearly every ecosystem from
>   marine (salt water) to fresh water, to soils, and from the polar
>   regions to the tropics, as well as the highest to the lowest of
>   elevations. They are ubiquitous in freshwater, marine, and terrestrial
>   environments, where they often outnumber other animals in both
>   individual and species counts, and are found in locations as diverse
>   as mountains, deserts and oceanic trenches. They are found in every
>   part of the earth's lithosphere,[7] even at great depths, 0.9–3.6 km
>   (3,000–12,000 ft), below the surface of the Earth in gold mines in
>   South Africa.[8][9][10][11][12] They represent 90% of all animals on
>   the ocean floor.[13] Their numerical dominance, often exceeding a
>   million individuals per square meter and accounting for about 80% of
>   all individual animals on earth, their diversity of life cycles, and
>   their presence at various trophic levels point at an important role in
>   many ecosystems.[14] The many parasitic forms include pathogens in
>   most plants and animals (including humans).[15] Some nematodes can
>   undergo cryptobiosis.

There are good odds that a nematode-based radiation of new lifeforms could expand to fill the now empty ecological niches. This presumably will take a long time even in geological terms.

One aspect of post-catastrophe worlds and the new lifeforms that might arise to fill it, is the simple fact that ninety percent of all life on Earth is microbiological. There is an excellent chance microbes will survive even an asteroid cluster bombardment. They're hardly the most attractive alternative to mammals and reptiles and all the usual multicellular organisms, but they are there and they will survive.

The question essentially assumes the non-survival of most large animals (this includes most multicellular organisms and may include insects) and the majority of plants. Those conditions are likely to lead to the mas extinction of effectively everything above the microbial in terms of size. if this is so, it will take, at least, tens of and possibly up to hundreds of millions for evolution to produce larger organisms like rodents, dogs and cats (in terms of size and complexity) to occupy the Earth's ecological niches.

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful to wipe out plant life completely on land. As asteroid would cause a nuclear winter like event and seeds can remain frozen for many many years.

Also like plants many insects can also remain frozen. There would also be the possibility of small mammals that would survive after all, it was the asteroid that wiped out the dinosaurs that enabled mammals to become the dominant species.

What is most likely is the larger lifeforms would become extinct. Anything bigger than a rat would be in trouble

See the [Chicxulub Crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater) for the effects of the asteroid that wiped out the dinosaurs.

That was 66 million years ago and in all likelihood evolution would follow a similar path where small mammals would be the dominant species

Comment: 65 million years ago, surely?

Comment: @HarryWeasley http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-glasgow-west-21379024 66 is a defended estimate.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Okay, I was just used to the figure 65!